# Self-hosting ASP.NET Core Web API is causing an error - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am self-hosting an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API application using `https` options.

These are my hosted server details

- Computer Name: padevspal203
- Domain Name: padev.local

Now I created a self signed certificate using this PowerShell command,

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName PADEVSPAL203.PADEV.LOCAL -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Also exporting certificate and place in C: drive.

Here is code for creating host builder with Kestrel configuration,

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {
                        serverOptions.AddServerHeader = false;
                        serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 44321, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\cert\test.pfx", "Password1"));
                        });
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Now when trying to browse api get method,getting below error. What wrong here?

```
https://PADEVSPAL203.PADEV.LOCAL:44321/WeatherForecast
```

> [Fiddler] The connection to 'padevspal203.padev.local' failed.
>
> Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [2002:aca8:2a2::aca8:2a2]:44321

Comment: Your web api listens only loopback interface, i.e `localhost`, but you do requests at `PADEVSPAL203.PADEV.LOCAL:44321`. Try to change any of them - web api configuration or just change your requests to localhost-based.

Comment: Thanks.  How to change loop back configuration and where?

Comment: Well you have `serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback` ... Instead of that there's also ListenAnyIP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.listenanyip?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks @James. now I am able to get the result of api in machine where I am hosted the app, but can't get result on other machine within same domain. I also copied same  certificate to other machine as well. Could you please suggest.